# How to get the initial value of style properties in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my html file I have the following markup:

```
<div class="long_box">
    <div class="image1">  <img src="images/image1.png">  </div>
    <div class="image2">  <img src="images/image2.png">  </div>
    <div class="image3">  <img src="images/image3.png">  </div>
</div>
```

In the css file I have applied the following style rules:

```
.long_box {
    width: 3300px;
    height: 768px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0;
}
```

In the javascript file I made a variable as:

```
var longbox = document.getElementsByClassName("long_box")[0];
```

Now when I try to recall the initial value of `left` of `long_box` as `longbox.style.left`, I get an empty string `""`. But after I change the `left` value with javascript, e.g. as as `longbox.style.left = 100 + 'px` and then recall it's value then I get `100px` in the console. So,

How to get the initial value of style properties in javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by "initial value"? Do you mean the CSS definition of "initial value", or something else?

Comment: you can try using the attr() to retrieve the value

Comment: @BoltClock By initial value I mean the values assigned in the css file -- which might get altered by javascript later. And after altering them I can somehow access them -- Maybe because `this.style.left = 100 + 'px'` adds inline styles.

Comment: You can't get the old style back if you've already changed it, or rather, you could, but that would require parsing all stylesheets to look for that style, or storing the old value before you change it.

Comment: @adeneo I don't want the old styles after changing them. I thought that `this.style.left` only works after changing the value of left. But now I got that `this.style.left`1 actually gives the inline styles.

Comment: This question is unfortunately worded. Is there a way to get the initial value of a style as it would be given by the CSS initial keyword, which sets the property back to how it would be in the CSS spec?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascripts `element.style` only returns inline styles, for other styles, for instance set in a stylesheet, you'd have to use `getComputedStyle`

```
var longbox = document.getElementsByClassName("long_box")[0];

var styles  = window.getComputedStyle(longbox);

var lef     = styles.getPropertyValue("left");
```

Comment: I am curious. When you refer to `inline styles` do you mean the styles that are directly on the html?

Comment: Yes, javascript sets inline styles directly on the elements

Comment: Can I define `longbox.style = getComputedStyle(longbox)`?

Comment: No, you can't overwrite the `element.style` object completely, you can only set each style, but there is the `cssText` style, which can set multiple styles

Comment: @adeneo Ok, thanks for clarify it :P